# Stop working of submit button after the last day to submit set by admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, gridview

I have a grid view and and a text box which submits the value after click of submit button. I have set a last date to submit the value.

Now I want that after that date, no one should be able to write or submit any new values.

In a nutshell I want to disable that text box after a date set by the admin.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are populating the grid from a SharePoint list.

A gridview includes many list items. So this depends on your requirement whether to give each item a unique date of expiration or to the entire list.

If it is at item level, you should have a separate column and put the number of days as a separate column. Then you can perform a comparison to display a different logic at each row of the gridview.

If it is at the list level, I would suggest you define a [web property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.properties.aspx) and set the expiration date on that. Then modify the data source to the gridview with a hidden column on allow editing or not. This column value will be based on whether the number of days passed or not. Then depending on that value, enable/disable editing.